# could not connect with a different internet connection(EasyRTC)

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, webrtc, easyrtc

Good day every I'm having a trouble about the livestream software i am making.

[image]

So in the first picture as you see there's a floating circle on the upper left corner of the video

[image]

and in this 2nd picture I'm trying to feed the image to the first picture.
but the problem is that it doesn't work here is what in my

**server.js**

```
// Load required modules
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');  // serve static files
var socketIo = require("socket.io");        // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("../");               // EasyRTC external module

// Set process name
process.title = "node-easyrtc";

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.
var app = express();
app.use(serveStatic('static', {'index': ['index.html']}));



var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
// Start Express http server on port 8080
var webServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = socketIo.listen(webServer, {"log level":3});

// Overriding the default easyrtcAuth listener, only so we can directly access its callback
easyrtc.events.on("easyrtcAuth", function(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, callback) {
easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.easyrtcAuth(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, function(err, connectionObj){
    if (err || !msg.msgData || !msg.msgData.credential || !connectionObj)     {
        callback(err, connectionObj);
        return;
    }

    connectionObj.setField("credential", msg.msgData.credential, {"isShared":false});

    console.log("["+easyrtcid+"] Credential saved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));

    callback(err, connectionObj);
});
});

// To test, lets print the credential to the console for every room join!
easyrtc.events.on("roomJoin", function(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback) {
console.log("["+connectionObj.getEasyrtcid()+"] Credential retrieved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));
easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.roomJoin(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback);
});

// Start EasyRTC server
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(app, socketServer, null, function(err, rtcRef) {
console.log("Initiated");

rtcRef.events.on("roomCreate", function(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback) {
    console.log("roomCreate fired! Trying to create: " + roomName);

    appObj.events.defaultListeners.roomCreate(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback);
});
});


easyrtc.on("getIceConfig", function(connectionObj, callback) {

// This object will take in an array of XirSys STUN and TURN servers
var iceConfig = [];

http.request({ 
    url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
    qs: {
        ident: "***",
        secret: "***",
        domain: "***",
        application: "default",
        room: "default",
        secure: 1
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // body.d.iceServers is where the array of ICE servers lives
            iceConfig = body.d.iceServers;  
            console.log(iceConfig);
            callback(null, iceConfig);
        }
    }
});

});


//listen on port 8080
webServer.listen(8080, function () {
console.log('listening on http://localhost:'+port);
});
```

and in my

**multistream.js**

```
var selfEasyrtcid = "";
var haveSelfVideo = false;
var otherEasyrtcid = null;


function disable(domId) {
console.log("about to try disabling "  +domId);
document.getElementById(domId).disabled = "disabled";
}


function enable(domId) {
console.log("about to try enabling "  +domId);
document.getElementById(domId).disabled = "";
}

function createLabelledButton(buttonLabel) {
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute('type','button');
button.setAttribute('class','btn btn-danger btn-circle waves-effect waves-circle waves-float');
button.innerHTML = "<i class='material-icons'>camera_enhance</i>";
document.getElementById("videoSrcBlk").appendChild(button);
return button;
}

function addMediaStreamToDiv(divId, stream, streamName, isLocal)
{
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.marginBottom = "10px";
var formattedName = streamName.replace("(", "<br>").replace(")", "");
var labelBlock = document.createElement("div");
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute('class','easyrtcMirror instructor-vid');
video.setAttribute('id','selfVideo');
video.style.width = "100%";
video.muted = isLocal;
video.style.verticalAlign= "middle";
container.appendChild(video);
document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(container);
video.autoplay = true;
easyrtc.setVideoObjectSrc(video, stream);
return labelBlock;
}

function addMediaStreamToDivClient(divId, stream, streamName, isLocal)
{
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.marginBottom = "10px";
var formattedName = streamName.replace("(", "<br>").replace(")", "");
var labelBlock = document.createElement("button");
labelBlock.setAttribute('class','btn btn-warning btn-circle-lg userlive waves-effect waves-circle waves-float');
labelBlock.style.width = "100px";
labelBlock.style.height = "100px";
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute('class','student-vid');
video.setAttribute('id','selfVideo');
video.muted = isLocal;
labelBlock.appendChild(video);
container.appendChild(labelBlock);
document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(container);
video.autoplay = true;
easyrtc.setVideoObjectSrc(video, stream);
return labelBlock;
}

function createLocalVideo(stream, streamName) {
var labelBlock = addMediaStreamToDiv("localVideos", stream, streamName, true);
var closeButton = createLabelledButton("close");
closeButton.onclick = function() {
    easyrtc.closeLocalStream(streamName);
    labelBlock.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(labelBlock.parentNode);
}
labelBlock.appendChild(closeButton);

console.log("created local video, stream.streamName = " + stream.streamName);
}

function addSrcButton(buttonLabel, videoId) {
var button = createLabelledButton(buttonLabel);
button.onclick = function() {
    easyrtc.setVideoSource(videoId);
    easyrtc.initMediaSource(
            function(stream) {
                createLocalVideo(stream, buttonLabel);
                if( otherEasyrtcid) {
                    easyrtc.addStreamToCall(otherEasyrtcid, buttonLabel, function(easyrtcid, streamName){
                        easyrtc.showError("Informational", "other party " + easyrtcid + " acknowledges receiving " + streamName);
                    });
                }
            },
            function(errCode, errText) {
                easyrtc.showError(errCode, errText);
            }, buttonLabel);
};
}

function connect() {
console.log("Initializing.");
easyrtc.setRoomOccupantListener(convertListToButtons);
easyrtc.connect("easyrtc.multistream", loginSuccess, loginFailure);
easyrtc.setAutoInitUserMedia(false);
easyrtc.getVideoSourceList(function(videoSrcList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < videoSrcList.length; i++) {
         var videoEle = videoSrcList[i];
        var videoLabel = (videoSrcList[i].label &&videoSrcList[i].label.length > 0)?
        (videoSrcList[i].label):("src_" + i);
        addSrcButton(videoLabel, videoSrcList[i].deviceId);
    }
});
}

function hangup() {
easyrtc.hangupAll();
disable('hangupButton');
}


function clearConnectList() {
var otherClientDiv = document.getElementById('otherClients');
while (otherClientDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
    otherClientDiv.removeChild(otherClientDiv.lastChild);
}
}


function convertListToButtons(roomName, occupants, isPrimary) {
clearConnectList();
var otherClientDiv = document.getElementById('otherClients');
for (var easyrtcid in occupants) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('class','col-md-3 btn bg-red btn-block btn-lg waves-effect');
    button.onclick = function(easyrtcid) {
        return function() {
            performCall(easyrtcid);
        };
    }(easyrtcid);

    var label = document.createTextNode("Student no.: " + easyrtc.idToName(easyrtcid));
    button.appendChild(label);
    otherClientDiv.appendChild(button);
}
}


function performCall(targetEasyrtcId) {
var acceptedCB = function(accepted, easyrtcid) {
    if (!accepted) {
        easyrtc.showError("CALL-REJECTED", "Sorry, your call to " + easyrtc.idToName(easyrtcid) + " was rejected");
        enable('otherClients');
    }
    else {
        otherEasyrtcid = targetEasyrtcId;
    }
};

var successCB = function() {
    enable('hangupButton');
};
var failureCB = function() {
    enable('otherClients');
};
var keys = easyrtc.getLocalMediaIds();

easyrtc.call(targetEasyrtcId, successCB, failureCB, acceptedCB, keys);
enable('hangupButton');
}


function loginSuccess(easyrtcid) {
disable("connectButton");
//  enable("disconnectButton");
enable('otherClients');
selfEasyrtcid = easyrtcid;
document.getElementById("iam").innerHTML = "Connected!";
// document.getElementById("iam").innerHTML = "Connected, waiting for class room" + easyrtc.cleanId(easyrtcid);
}

function loginFailure(errorCode, message) {
easyrtc.showError(errorCode, message);
}


function disconnect() {
document.getElementById("iam").innerHTML = "logged out";
easyrtc.disconnect();
enable("connectButton");
clearConnectList();
easyrtc.setVideoObjectSrc(document.getElementById('selfVideo'), "");
}

easyrtc.setStreamAcceptor(function(easyrtcid, stream, streamName) {
var labelBlock = addMediaStreamToDivClient("remoteVideos", stream, streamName, false);
labelBlock.parentNode.id = "remoteBlock" + easyrtcid + streamName;
console.log("accepted incoming stream with name " + stream.streamName);
console.log("checking incoming " + easyrtc.getNameOfRemoteStream(easyrtcid, stream));
});



easyrtc.setOnStreamClosed(function(easyrtcid, stream, streamName) {
var item = document.getElementById("remoteBlock" + easyrtcid + streamName);
item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
});


var callerPending = null;

easyrtc.setCallCancelled(function(easyrtcid) {
if (easyrtcid === callerPending) {
    document.getElementById('acceptCallBox').style.display = "none";
    callerPending = false;
}
});

easyrtc.setAcceptChecker(function(easyrtcid, callback) {
otherEasyrtcid = easyrtcid;
if (easyrtc.getConnectionCount() > 0) {
    easyrtc.hangupAll();
}
callback(true, easyrtc.getLocalMediaIds());
});
```

And on heroku log here is what it says:

> 2017-05-24T15:40:05.352716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lmx7G8z&sid=x2x-q9gk8gJmiJW3AAAC" host=shielded-sands-69548.herokuapp.com request_id=1a3911f4-e809-42f9-8008-c1ab4ac5d860 fwd="121.54.32.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=62ms status=200 bytes=559 protocol=https
>   2017-05-24T15:40:07.182964+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] EasyRTC command received with msgType [setRoomApiField]
>   2017-05-24T15:40:07.184033+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Running func 'onMsgTypeSetRoomApiField' with apiFieldObj:  { roomName: [32m'default'[39m,
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.184035+00:00 app[web.1]:   field:
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.184035+00:00 app[web.1]:    { mediaIds:
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.184036+00:00 app[web.1]:       { fieldName: [32m'mediaIds'[39m,
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.184037+00:00 app[web.1]:         fieldValue: { [32m'USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (04f2:b409)'[39m: [32m'7G0CSKTl143ui0S8P3o3I6ODKqkmcb6c9x2J'[39m } } } }
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.193658+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.emitRoomDataDelta'
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:07.193760+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.generateRoomDataDelta'
>       Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:30.732318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lmx7TgQ&sid=2GH0CYMLf5N1yMSoAAAD" host=shielded-sands-69548.herokuapp.com request_id=b3e85b00-1631-4a86-ac37-d30e7da18e5a fwd="112.198.82.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=44ms status=200 bytes=559 protocol=https
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.058485+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lmx7Tlt&sid=2GH0CYMLf5N1yMSoAAAD" host=shielded-sands-69548.herokuapp.com request_id=4eca076e-77d4-4c79-81f8-85b0bc87f474 fwd="112.198.82.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=225 protocol=https
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492099+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] EasyRTC command received with msgType [setRoomApiField]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492866+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] Running func 'onMsgTypeSetRoomApiField' with apiFieldObj:  { roomName: [32m'default'[39m,
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492869+00:00 app[web.1]:   field:
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492869+00:00 app[web.1]:    { mediaIds:
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492870+00:00 app[web.1]:       { fieldName: [32m'mediaIds'[39m,
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.492871+00:00 app[web.1]:         fieldValue: { [32m'camera 1, facing front'[39m: [32m'jyQhLuKAb3xFwMnpx4316IazXWfq8OjpllXN'[39m } } } }
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.493276+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.emitRoomDataDelta'
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.493368+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.generateRoomDataDelta'
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:31.493579+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [roomData]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.147874+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] EasyRTC command received with msgType [offer]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.148264+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [offer]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.771088+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] EasyRTC message received of type [easyrtc_streamReceived]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.778244+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcMsg' with msgType [easyrtc_streamReceived]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.825123+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] EasyRTC command received with msgType [answer]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.825572+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [answer]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.835961+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.836259+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][s4kVZlTHTPBuXAsq] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.880085+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] EasyRTC command received with msgType [setUserCfg]
>
> 2017-05-24T15:40:35.880411+00:00 app[web.1]: debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.multistream][GbiiKUGLqDt10wqa] WebRTC setUserCfg command received. This feature is not yet complete.

can anyone please try to help me :(

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: Yup this has been resolved too long ago :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you help me out?

Comment: Sure . Are we exactly have the same issue???

Comment: If we have then you just need to create a stun and turn server. You could use the free stun and turn server of xirsys. Hope it helps your issue.

Comment: @I am using free STUN server and setup own TURN server. now getting `buildPeerConnection failed, call not completed` error. I have posted my config [here](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc/issues/383) can you please have look?

Comment: What stun server are you using . Could you try first the xirsys :)

Comment: `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302, stun:stun.sipgate.net, stun:stun.sipgate.net:10000` Yes I can, actually I need to run this via own server. Please have look at me configuration https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc/issues/383

Comment: Here maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213472/error-on-getting-ice-config-in-xirsys