# Error on getting Ice Config in Xirsys

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, easyrtc, xirsys

I'm having a trouble on looking for the error can anyone point it out for me please i have been into this for 2 days and still can't figure it out.

[image: error log]

the picture above is the error log from heroku.

and here is my **server.js** for the ice configuration

```
// Load required modules
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var https = require('https');
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');  // serve static files
var socketIo = require("socket.io");        // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require('./lib/easyrtc_server');              // EasyRTC external module

// Set process name
process.title = "node-easyrtc";
```

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.

```
var app = express();

app.use(serveStatic('public', {'index': ['index.html']}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

// Start Express http server on port 8080

```
var webServer = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server

```
var socketServer = socketIo.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});




easyrtc.setOption("logLevel", "debug");
```

// Overriding the default easyrtcAuth listener, only so we can directly access its callback

```
easyrtc.events.on("easyrtcAuth", function(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, callback) {
easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.easyrtcAuth(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, function(err, connectionObj){
    if (err || !msg.msgData || !msg.msgData.credential || !connectionObj)     
{
        callback(err, connectionObj);
        return;
    }

    connectionObj.setField("credential", msg.msgData.credential, {"isShared":false});

    console.log("["+easyrtcid+"] Credential saved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));

    callback(err, connectionObj);
});
});
```

// To test, lets print the credential to the console for every room join!

```
easyrtc.events.on("roomJoin", function(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback) {

console.log("["+connectionObj.getEasyrtcid()+"] Credential retrieved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));

easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.roomJoin(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback);
});
```

// Start EasyRTC server

```
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(app, socketServer, null, function(err, rtcRef) {
console.log("Initiated");

rtcRef.events.on("roomCreate", function(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback) {
    console.log("roomCreate fired! Trying to create: " + roomName);

    appObj.events.defaultListeners.roomCreate(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback);
});
});
```

//ice config easyrtc

```
easyrtc.on("getIceConfig", function(connectionObj, callback) {

// This object will take in an array of XirSys STUN and TURN servers
var iceConfig = [];

http.request({ 
    url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
    qs: {
        ident: "***",
        secret: "****",
        domain: "***",
        application: "test-livestream",
        room: "test-livestream-room",
        secure: 1
},
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // body.d.iceServers is where the array of ICE servers lives
        iceConfig = body.d.iceServers;  
        console.log(iceConfig);
        callback(null, iceConfig);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
    }
});
});
```

//listen on port 8080

```
webServer.listen(8080, function () {

console.log('listening on http://localhost:'+port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding another module

```
var request = require("request");
```

and editting my ice server

```
request.post('https://service.xirsys.com/ice',{
    form:{
        ident: "****",
        secret: "****",
        domain: "****",
        application: "****",
        room: "****",
        secure: 1
    },
    json:true
 },
```

i obtain to let it work :)